# Java factory pattern using generic constraints

Tags: java, factory-pattern, generic-constraints

I have

```
public class  MyFactory()
{
   public static <T> T getItem(Element element, Class<T> clazz)
   {
         T item = null;
         if (clazz == IFoo.class)
         {
              item =  (T) new Foo();
         }
         else if (clazz == IBar.class)
         {
              item =  (T) new Bar();
         }
         ...

        assert item instanceof IParsable;
        (IParsable(foo)).parse(element)

       return item;
   }

}
```

and then I call it like this

```
IFoo parsedFoo = MyFactory.getItem(someElement, IFoo.class);
```

Here the concrete classes implement `IParsable` . Would I be able to remove the runtime assert check and put a compile time check to see if 'IParsable' and call parse?

Also I was wondering if there is a way to enforce IFoo<-->Foo implements relationship at compile time in `getItem()` method and remove the typecasting `(T)` ?

EDIT: I thought I would give an outline for `IFoo` and `Foo`

```
public interface IFoo
{
    String getFooName();
    int getFooId();
    ....
}


class Foo implements IFoo, IParsable
{
      ...
}
```

EDIT2:

I just thought of a refactoring like this, now the only thing that's not a compile time check is the relation between interface and implementation.

```
  public static <U extends IParsable, T> T getItem(Element element, Class<T> clazz)
   {
         U item = null;
         if (clazz == IFoo.class)
         {
              item =  (U) new Foo();
         }
         else if (clazz == IBar.class)
         {
              item =  (U) new Bar();
         }
         ...

       item.parse(element)

       return (T) item;
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
public static <T> T getItem(Element element, Class<T> clazz) {
    IParsable item = null;
    if (clazz == IFoo.class) {
        item = new Foo();
    } else if (clazz == IBar.class) {
        item = new Bar();
    }
    item.parse();
    return (T) item;
}
```

The fact that `Foo` is an `IParsable` is checked at compile time. The other cast (to `(T)`) is still a runtime exercise - but it was also the case in your example.

Comment: actually, this never checks that Foo is castable to IFoo, since a generic cast like that is erased at runtime.

Comment: what you want is `return clazz.cast(item);`.

Answer (score 1):

Here the concrete classes implement IParsable . Would I be able to remove the runtime assert check and put a compile time check to see if 'IParsable' and call parse?

```
From what I know - no, it's not possible. You will be passing object to this method at runtime, the compiler has no idea what objects will be passed. So compile time is not an option here.
```

Also I was wondering if there is a way to enforce IFoo<-->Foo implements relationship at compile time in getItem() method and remove the typecasting (T) ?

```
Again, only at runtime with isAssignableFrom
```

Answer (score 1):

you should register all the mappings at class setup time like this (it's ugly cause you can't check more than one bounds with the same type parameter):

```
private static Map<Class<?>, Class<?>> MAPPINGS = ...;

static {
  registerMapping(IFoo.class, Foo.class, Foo.class);
  // ...
}

private static <IT, TT extends IT, TP extends IParseable> void registerMapping(Class<IT> ifaceClazz, Class<TT> implClazz, TP parseableClazz) {
  MAPPINGS.put(ifaceClazz, implClazz);
}
```

then in `getItem()` your if block turns into a simple map lookup.  note, this will not get rid of the `(T)` cast, but there's nothing you can do about that.

Comment: Does `TT extends IT & IParseable` compile?

Comment: `TT extends IT & IParseable` will not compile, I don't think.